# Numbers not keeping format when exported from SSRS 2008 R2 to Excel 2010

Tags: reporting-services

I am using an expression to display currency depending on if the value is in the millions or in the thousands. This expression is set in the Format property of my report:

```
=iif((Fields!PrevActual.Value < 100000), "'$'#,,0,'K';('$'#,0,'K')", "'$'0,,.0,'M';('$'0,,.0,'M')'")
```

In this way, if the value is 1,500,000 the number will display as $1.5M and if it's 15,000 it will display as $15k.

The problem is when I export the file to Excel. The numbers in the thousands retain the formatting, but the numbers in the millions lose it. So I have a spreadsheet with numbers like 1,500,000 and $15k.  All numbers are exporting as text.

Does anyone know of a way to keep the formatting in excel so it matches how it's displayed on the SSRS report while making sure it's also still a number?

Essentially, I want to mimic what excel was doing before we automated this report with SSRS. Numbers in the millions were in this custom number format: $#.0,,\M and thousands were in this one: $#,K.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you export the excel formula then it can work. i.e. export 
="text(1500000," ""'$'0,,.0,'M';('$'0,,.0,'M')"")"

Excel will then convert the formula to the final formatted value
$15M

The tricky part is making the format string valid in excel, and creating an SSRS formula which will concatenate strings and generate an Excel formula.

This can help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159220%28SQL.90%29.aspx